# unexpected left while doing self left join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, groovy, hql

I am trying to do self left join on same table multiple times. whenever I execute this query I am getting exception.

**Class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException**
**Message unexpected token: LEFT near line 13, column 33**

```
Query query = null
        def hql = $/
                SELECT
                    c1.id,
                    c1.parentId,
                    c1.navDepth,
                    c1.navOrder,
                    c1.title,
                    c1.fileName,
                    // aliasing filenamepath column as filepath.
                    REPLACE(c1.fileNamePath, 'home/', '') AS filepath
                FROM Content AS c1

                WHERE 0 = 0
                LEFT JOIN Content AS c2
                ON c1.col1 = c2.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col1 = c2.col1

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c3
                ON c1.col2 = c3.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col2 = c3.col2

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c4
                ON c1.col3 = c4.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col3 = c4.col3

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c5
                ON c1.col4 = c5.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col4 = c5.col4

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c6
                ON c1.col5 = c6.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col5 = c6.col5

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c7
                ON c1.col6 = c7.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col6 = c7.col6

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c8
                ON c1.col7 = c8.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col7 = c8.col7

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c9
                ON c1.col8 = c9.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col8 = c9.col8

                LEFT JOIN Content AS c10
                ON c1.col9 = c10.fileNameLookup
                AND c1.col9 = c10.col9

                AND c1.isNavItem = 1
                GROUP BY c1.id
                ORDER BY c1.navDepth, c1.navOrder
                /$
                //def result = Content.executeQuery(hql)
        query = Content.executeQuery(hql).setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
                .addScalar("filepath", new StringType())
        List<Map<String,Object>> result = query.list()
        return result
```

can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong in it, how can i make it working ?

Answer (score 1):

1. The WHERE is misplaced:

   ```
   FROM 
   WHERE 0 = 0
   LEFT JOIN Content AS c2
   ```

   It should be:

   ```
   FROM
   LEFT JOIN
   LEFT JOIN
   ...
   WHERE
   GROUP BY
   ORDER BY
   ```
2. There's no **filepath** parameter to set in your query, and if it would have to be in the WHERE clause not in the SELECT clause:

   ```
   addScalar("filepath", new StringType())
   ```
3. You wrote an SQL query with LEFT JOINS and ON clauses, but that's the native SQL query syntax. In HQL you join navigable entity associations and there's no HQL ON clause.

   To emulate the ON clause you need to use [the **with** directive](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

   ```
   from Cat as cat
       left join cat.kittens as kitten
           with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
   ```
4. Try it without a transformer first. Just execute the query and let it return a List first. If that works then try with the transformer. If it doesn't you still have issues in your query syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Now I am still getting same exception but with different message saying `content is not mapped`.

Comment: I have removed the transformer execute it getting still same exception but with different message saying `path expected for join!`.

Comment: I have removed the `ON` clause while joining now it saying that unexpected token c1. is I am doing aliasing right ?